# Bootstrap Accordion Items are Spaced Weird

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I am working on this project and playing with the Bootstrap Accordion. It seems that my accordion items are overlapping on top of each other, sometimes within the container, and sometimes on top of the other containers.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

I have tried adding containers, but it seems to mess up the accordion.

I would also like to add space under the accordion, but am not sure if adding margins or spacers underneath of it would make it less responsive.

Screenshots:
[Accordion 1](https://imgur.com/KcVZsP6https://) `[

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(143,25,154,1), rgba(200, 5, 158, 0.8));
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
  }
.sectionOne {
    background-image: url(imageFolder/background.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.display-1 {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.accordion-title {
    font-variant-caps: titling-caps;
    position: absoulte;
}

.accordion-button {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Red Rose;
    color: #FEB7EE !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.accordion-button:after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23FEB7EE'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") !important;
    margin-right:0;
    color: rgb(224, 16, 176) !important;
  }
.accordion-button:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23E010B0'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") !important;
}
.accordion-button collapse {
    color: rgb(224, 16, 176);
  }
 .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
    color: rgb(224, 16, 176) !important;
    background-color: rgb(254, 183,238, .8);
}
h2 {
    font-family: Red Rose;
    color: #FEB7EE;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h4 {
    font-family: Raleway;
    color: #FEB7EE;
}
p {
    font-family: Raleway;
}

  }
  a {
    color: #73C3E8;
  }
img {
    position: absolute;
}
.backgroundElipse {
    position:center;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px !important;
}
.btn{
    margin-top: 50px !important;
    margin-left: 25px !important;
    color: #FEB7EE !important;
    background-color: #49276D !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-family: Raleway;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    position: center;
}
```

```html
<!--html-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--javascript-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Red+Rose&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-4dNpRvNX0c/TdYEbYup8qbjvjaMrgUPh+g4I03CnNtANuv+VAvPL6LqdwzZKV38G" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--title and favicon-->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">
      <!--section1-->
      <div class="sectionOne">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!--intro-->
            <div class="row">
              <h2 class="display-1">Raspberry Pi for Designers</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="display-7">The Raspberry Pi may be a computer smaller than a deck of cards, but you’ll be
                surprised what it can do!</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="#learnMore">Learn More</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row-sm-6">
              <img class="backgroundElipse" src="imageFolder/raspElipse.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!--accordion-->
  
  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  
    <!--about-->
    <a id="learnMore">
    <div class="accordion-item"></a>
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushAbout">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne" onclick="about"
          ()>
          About
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body about">
          <p><strong>Raspberry Pi is a</strong> fully featured, low cost, tiny Linux computer that is an easy
            way to learn programming and computing.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--ingredients-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushIngredients">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
          What You'll Need
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col"><img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="raspberry pi icon" width="100" height="100">
              </div>
            </div>
            </h2>
            <div class="col">
              <h3>Raspberry Pi</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>Go with models 3 and higher.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="hdmi monitor icon" width="100" height="100">
        <h3>HDMI Monitor</h3>
        <p>An HDMI TV works too!</p>
        <img src="" alt="SD card icon" class="img-fluid" width="100" height="100">
        <h3>SD Card</h3>
        <p>Aim for at least 8GB.</p>
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="USB Mouse" width="100" height="100">
        <h3>USB Mouse</h3>
        <p>You can switch to a wireless mouse later.</p>
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="USB Keyboard icon" width="100" height="100">
        <h3>USB Keyboard</h3>
        <p>You can switch to a wireless keyboard later.</p>
        <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="power supply icon" width="100" height="100">
        <h3>Power Supply</h3>
        <p>Standard 5V USB C or Micro depending on the model.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--SetUp-->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSetUp">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
        Set Up
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree"
      data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <h4>Set up your SD card.</h4>
        <p>Install the operating system onto the SD card. </p>
        <a href="https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md"> Link to download the NOOBS
          Operating
          System </a>
        <h4>Plug everything in.</h4>
        <img src="programming.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="Computer Man" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        <p>Make sure everything is plugged in before turning it on.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--options-->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushOptions">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#flush-collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseFour">
        What Can You Do?
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingFour"
      data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
              <div id="random_number1" class="carousel slide youtube-carousel" data-ride="carousel"
                data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="video-container item active">
                    <div class="youtube-video" id='AO89eXKO0c4'></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">Video 1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="video-container item">
                    <div class="youtube-video" id='6MjRVkm9CF0'></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">Video 2</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="video-container item ">
                    <div class="youtube-video" id='R8poo-zCK9g'></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">Video 3</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="prev">
                    <div class="left-button">
                      <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="next">
                    <div class="right-button">
                      <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--python-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushPython">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseFive">
          Code with Python
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="flush-collapseFive" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingFive"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <h4>Open Thonny</h4>
          <p>Use Thonny to create new programs and systems on your Raspberry Pi </p>
          <a href="url"> Link to see what you can do with Python </a>
          <h4>Learn Python</h4>
          <img src="programming.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="Computer Man" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--accessories-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushAccessories">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#flush-collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseSix">
          Add Ons & Accessories
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="flush-collapseSix" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingSix"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
                aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Camera</h5>
                  <p>Take some photos with your raspberry pi.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Touch Screen</h5>
                  <p>Have a fully handheld experience with this screen addition.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://www.adafruit.com/product/2707" class="d-block w-100"
                  alt="Pimironi Picade Game Controller">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Pimoroni Picade Console Controller</h5>
                  <p>For a retro gaming experience.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
              <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark"
                data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--sensehat-->
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSenseHat">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseSeven">
            SenseHat
          </button>

        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseSeven" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingSeven"
          data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
          <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="SenseHat Kiss" width="200" height="250">
          <pre>
  <code>
  from sense_hat import SenseHat
  sense = SenseHat()

  # Define some colours
  r = (255, 0, 0)
  p = (230, 0, 255)
  b = (0, 255, 247)
  
  O = (0, 0, 0)
  X = (255, 255, 0)

  # Get your SenseHat to give you a kiss
  kiss = [
  O, X, X, X, X, X, X, O,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  X, b, b, O, O, b, b, X,
  X, O, O, p, p, O, O, X,
  X, O, r, r, r, r, O, X,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  O, X, X, X, X, X, X, O
  ]
  # Display these colours on the LED matrix
    sense.set_pixels(kiss)
  </code>
  </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--projects-->
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSenseHat">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseEight" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseEight">
            SenseHat Projects
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseEight" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingEight"
          data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushEight">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <div class="card-group">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Project 1</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This will be a cool project idea.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Project 2</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Another cool project. </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Project 3</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Last cool project goes here.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--resources-->
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushResources">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseNine" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseNine">
            Raspberry Pi Resources
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseNine" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingNine"
          data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushNine">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Link</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Another Link</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Another another link</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Fourth link</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Last link</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end tag-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<link href="./stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V48tE.jpg)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of Bootstrap 3, 4, and 5 files. You should have just one set of Bootstrap files. Since you have code from bootstrap-5, I’m assuming that’s what you want to use (no support for IE11). You have files before the DOCTYPE and after the body closing tag. Some of your components are overlapping other components as you’re using position absolute for all images and a large top margin for at least one (backgroundElipse).

I cleaned up your file a little bit (deleted your img style and hid the backgroundElipse).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Red+Rose&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />



    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--title and favicon-->

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html {
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(143, 25, 154, 1), rgba(200, 5, 158, 0.8));
            opacity: 1;
            position: relative;
            overflow: scroll;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .sectionOne {
            background-image: url(imageFolder/background.png);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: 100% auto;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        .display-1 {
            margin-top: 200px;
        }

        .accordion-title {
            font-variant-caps: titling-caps;
            position: absoulte;
        }

        .accordion-button {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Red Rose;
            color: #FEB7EE !important;
            border: none !important;
        }

        .accordion-button:after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23FEB7EE'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") !important;
            margin-right: 0;
            color: rgb(224, 16, 176) !important;
        }

        .accordion-button:before {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23E010B0'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>") !important;
        }

        .accordion-button collapse {
            color: rgb(224, 16, 176);
        }

        .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
            color: rgb(224, 16, 176) !important;
            background-color: rgb(254, 183, 238, .8);
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Red Rose;
            color: #FEB7EE;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        h4 {
            font-family: Raleway;
            color: #FEB7EE;
        }

        p {
            font-family: Raleway;
        }

        a {
            color: #73C3E8;
        }

        .backgroundElipse {
            display: none;
            position: center;
            margin-top: 200px;
            margin-left: 50px !important;
        }

        .btn {
            margin-top: 50px !important;
            margin-left: 25px !important;
            color: #FEB7EE !important;
            background-color: #49276D !important;
            border: none !important;
            font-family: Raleway;
            max-width: 200px !important;
            position: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-12">
            <!--section1-->
            <div class="sectionOne">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <!--intro-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 class="display-1">Raspberry Pi for Designers</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class="display-7">The Raspberry Pi may be a computer smaller than a deck of cards, but you’ll be
                                surprised what it can do!</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" href="#learnMore">Learn More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row-sm-6">
                            <img class="backgroundElipse" src="imageFolder/raspElipse.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--accordion-->

    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">

        <!--about-->
        <a id="learnMore">
            <div class="accordion-item">
        </a>
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushAbout">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne" onclick="about" ()>
                About
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body about">
                <p><strong>Raspberry Pi is a</strong> fully featured, low cost, tiny Linux computer that is an easy
                    way to learn programming and computing.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--ingredients-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushIngredients">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                What You'll Need
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col"><img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="raspberry pi icon" width="100" height="100">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>Raspberry Pi</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Go with models 3 and higher.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="hdmi monitor icon" width="100" height="100">
            <h3>HDMI Monitor</h3>
            <p>An HDMI TV works too!</p>
            <img src="" alt="SD card icon" class="img-fluid" width="100" height="100">
            <h3>SD Card</h3>
            <p>Aim for at least 8GB.</p>
            <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="USB Mouse" width="100" height="100">
            <h3>USB Mouse</h3>
            <p>You can switch to a wireless mouse later.</p>
            <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="USB Keyboard icon" width="100" height="100">
            <h3>USB Keyboard</h3>
            <p>You can switch to a wireless keyboard later.</p>
            <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="power supply icon" width="100" height="100">
            <h3>Power Supply</h3>
            <p>Standard 5V USB C or Micro depending on the model.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--SetUp-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSetUp">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                Set Up
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <h4>Set up your SD card.</h4>
                <p>Install the operating system onto the SD card. </p>
                <a href="https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md"> Link to download the NOOBS
                    Operating
                    System </a>
                <h4>Plug everything in.</h4>
                <img src="programming.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="Computer Man" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                <p>Make sure everything is plugged in before turning it on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--options-->
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushOptions">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseFour">
                What Can You Do?
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="flush-collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingFour" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <div id="random_number1" class="carousel slide youtube-carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="video-container item active">
                                        <div class="youtube-video" id='AO89eXKO0c4'></div>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">Video 1</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="video-container item">
                                        <div class="youtube-video" id='6MjRVkm9CF0'></div>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">Video 2</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="video-container item ">
                                        <div class="youtube-video" id='R8poo-zCK9g'></div>
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">Video 3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="prev">
                                        <div class="left-button">
                                            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="next">
                                        <div class="right-button">
                                            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--python-->
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushPython">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseFive">
                    Code with Python
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseFive" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingFive" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <h4>Open Thonny</h4>
                    <p>Use Thonny to create new programs and systems on your Raspberry Pi </p>
                    <a href="url"> Link to see what you can do with Python </a>
                    <h4>Learn Python</h4>
                    <img src="programming.gif" class="img-fluid" alt="Computer Man" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--accessories-->
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushAccessories">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseSix">
                    Add Ons & Accessories
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="flush-collapseSix" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingSix" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators">
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Camera</h5>
                                    <p>Take some photos with your raspberry pi.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Touch Screen</h5>
                                    <p>Have a fully handheld experience with this screen addition.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img src="https://www.adafruit.com/product/2707" class="d-block w-100" alt="Pimironi Picade Game Controller">
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Pimoroni Picade Console Controller</h5>
                                    <p>For a retro gaming experience.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                            </button>
                            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--sensehat-->
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSenseHat">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseSeven">
                        SenseHat
                    </button>

                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseSeven" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingSeven" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                    <img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="SenseHat Kiss" width="200" height="250">
                    <pre>
  <code>
  from sense_hat import SenseHat
  sense = SenseHat()

  # Define some colours
  r = (255, 0, 0)
  p = (230, 0, 255)
  b = (0, 255, 247)
  
  O = (0, 0, 0)
  X = (255, 255, 0)

  # Get your SenseHat to give you a kiss
  kiss = [
  O, X, X, X, X, X, X, O,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  X, b, b, O, O, b, b, X,
  X, O, O, p, p, O, O, X,
  X, O, r, r, r, r, O, X,
  X, O, O, O, O, O, O, X,
  O, X, X, X, X, X, X, O
  ]
  # Display these colours on the LED matrix
    sense.set_pixels(kiss)
  </code>
  </pre>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--projects-->
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushSenseHat">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseEight" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseEight">
                        SenseHat Projects
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseEight" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingEight" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushEight">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <div class="card-group">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Project 1</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">This will be a cool project idea.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Project 2</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Another cool project. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Project 3</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Last cool project goes here.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--resources-->
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flushResources">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseNine" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseNine">
                        Raspberry Pi Resources
                    </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="flush-collapseNine" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingNine" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushNine">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">Link</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Another Link</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Another another link</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Fourth link</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Last link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end tag-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a reason that you hid the img file? 

I tried your code but it seemed to not work, all of the styling has gone awry. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: When you say the styling when awry, what does that mean? If you run my code snippet, is it does it look okay? — In your CSS, you had set the `img` tag set to `position: absolute;` which puts the image over your text (hiding the text). If you float the image to the left (`.float-start`) and add `overflow-hidden` to the `accordion-body` div, then your text will wrap around your image and the accordion will expand to include the image. Because your backgroundElipse is a img, it was also positioned absolute, so it was extending down into the accordion section.

Comment: Oh I wanted that part on the actual title page and not in the accordion :) 

This is what I meant that it went a bit wonky- lost a lot of my spacing elements and the colours I had in the accordion weren't there in the new code. not sure why it happened that way! I will try to sort out the position. https://imgur.com/gallery/y0RYFEl